# Offline version of Stack Exchange for specific interest, for example, Python programming

Tags: discussion, data-dump, languages

I have no intent to post a duplicated thread here. I'm interested in an offline version of Stack Overflow where I can study on the run as my job is an interstate courier that does not always have an Internet connection. Using 3G data is very expensive though.

Is there a way to download an offline dump from the Stack Overflow for a specific programming language, for example, I'm learning [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29). Download the whole site seems not reasonable as it is too big and not necessary.

How do I browse it alike the "Outlook" style, for example, the title column and content panel?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created several books (physical and eBooks). I've update the Python eBook with data from the latest data dump (June 2016) and generated a Python physical book if you want that.

While not exactly what you're after (it's not quite "outlook style"), both books have links (eBook has hyperlinks, physical book as page numbers) between sections / tags so that you can read questions by tag, even if the book doesn't group the questions into the tag you want to read (because a more dominant tag exists for the question).

I've put a free promotion on the eBook for 5 days starting today.

eBook: [https://www.amazon.com/Python-Programming-Questions-George-Duckett-ebook/dp/B00RY621J6](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00RY621J6)

Physical Book: [https://www.amazon.com/Python-Programming-Questions-George-Duckett/dp/1535352752](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1535352752)

Hope you find one/them useful!

Comment: You did a great job George. Thank you sooooo much

Comment: These Amazon links are now dead, and I can't seem to find this title available elsewhere. What happened?

Comment: @Coquelicot Amazon got stricter with what they allow on their platform. You should be able to find equivalents on iTunes and the Google play store. (don't have the links to hand right now unfortunately).

Answer (score -1):

You can download the whole StackOverflow data dump in [archive.org](https://archive.org/download/stackexchange/), but you need to download a huge file and have a lot of space in your hard drive to uncompress it.

Alternatively, you can use StackExchange [Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/) with a query like:

```
SELECT TOP ##NumberOfQuestionsToFetch##
          question.Id AS QuestionId, 
          question.Score AS QuestionScore,
          question.Title AS QuestionTitle,
          question.Body AS QuestionBody,
          question.Tags,
          answer.Id AS AcceptedAnswerId,
          answer.Score AS AnswerScore,
          answer.Body AS AnswerBody
FROM Posts AS question
JOIN Posts AS answer on question.AcceptedAnswerId = answer.Id
INNER JOIN PostTags AS question_tags on question_tags.PostId = 
question.Id
INNER JOIN Tags on question_tags.TagId = Tags.Id
WHERE question.Id > ##LastFetchedQuestionId## AND 
      Tags.TagName IN ('##Tag##')
ORDER BY question.Id ASC
```

You can fetch 50000 questions at a time, but you repeat the search starting with the ID number of the last question of your previous batch.

Comment: That's just raw data dump. Stack Exchange got official place with the data dumps. Question here is about downloading specific set of questions, e.g. of one tag.