# Shouldn't there be a book published by Stack Exchange containing the archive of best questions with the top answers for a particular site(s)?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Stack Exchange is a great place to ask and answer, but at the same time due to its legacy it has grown up with some of the best quality of content expressed in the question-and-answer format. So, shouldn't there be a book that should incorporate all such content of a site?

I think it would be easy to discover and keep track of content in that format over web page based one. What do you think?

NB- The book could be made to be available in softcopy and/or hardcopy.

Comment: The licensing of the content is such that everybody is free to produce such a book (if they follow some basic rules of attribution). Some already did this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they do they might be late to the market: [Offline version of Stack Exchange for specific interest, for example, Python programming](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281366/offline-version-of-stack-exchange-for-specific-interest-for-example-python-pro)

Beyond that there are ways to create your own offline copy: [Printing out Stack Overflow/Exchange Q&As including comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22877/printing-out-stack-overflow-exchange-qas-including-comments)

And they already provide [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) on which I based [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/269951) to create an html page of your own content.

All in all I don't think it is extremely useful for Stack Exchange to do but others are free to provide such books as long as they provide proper attribution.

Answer (score 2):

The CC-BY-SA license means that anybody who wants to edit such a compilation is free to do so.  There's no reason for SE themselves to do so given that any interested community member can.

Doing it well requires work.  There are some e-books (you can find them on Amazon) that are mechanical dumps of questions from most sites; I suspect their selection is driven by a query.  I don't find them very useful.  On the other hand, a [curated collection](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1568/mi-yodeya-publications) can be quite valuable.  If you're thinking about producing a book from your favorite site, I suggest starting with a focused topic, selecting material on that topic, and editing it into a book format to see how it goes.